# Can't download adventure works database 2005 from codeplex

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database, sample, adventureworks

Can't download adventure works database 2005 from codeplex. Where else can I find and download it??? I've been searching it online, I found some results but i can't download any of them. Any help is appreciated

Comment: don't just view it, answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No response or solution found. Just gave up findin it.

Answer (score 0):

it's usually bundled with sql installation disks

Try this link for online download of sqlserver samples

[1](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4004)

[2](http://codeplex.com/SqlServerSamples)

Comment: I've already tried those links, they bring me at the same page I am
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here they are http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18407

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you couldn't find it, because a simple search for `adventure works` on the CodePlex website led me to the following URL:

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18407#ReleaseFiles

Comment: yep, me too, is there the posibility of a firewall or something like that, that doesn't allow me to download it?

Comment: I find the urls but i can't download them